# Hook ZwDeviceIoControlFile with patchguard enabled on Win 10 x64

Tags: windows, kernel, hook, windows-kernel

I need to change the output buffer whenever a call to `ZwDeviceIoControlFile` is made. Is it possible to hook `ZwDeviceIoControlFile` from within a kernel mode driver in Windows 10 x64 while Patchguard is enabled? If not, could I maybe use ObRegister callbacks to change its output buffer?

Would like to know if someone ever succeeded with this on Windows x64 while PG is enabled.

Comment: *hook* is impossible, *ObRegisterCallbacks* absolute unrelated to filter *ZwDeviceIoControlFile*. you go in wrong direction. you need filter/minifilter to driver which handle this *ioctl*

Comment: @RbMm Yeah I thought so it would be practically impossible. I will look into filter/minifilters, thanks!

Comment: at first you need filter not all *ioctls* in system but think some concrete (one or several) - so when you filter right device - you already very strong restrict request stream, which is good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a Hypervisor and using EPT to hide the actual hook when PG does a read operation on the region. I am able to fully hook kernel APIs without PG noticing on Win 10 x64.